# I am trying to set up an Adwords Script which automatically sends emails but this fails when email contains "-"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-ads-api

The Script I'm trying to set up uses the MailApp service to send emails to recipients included in a Ghseet.

```js
function sendProcessingEmail() {
  var customerId = AdsApp.currentAccount().getCustomerId();
  if (config.emailEachRun && config.emailRecipients &&
      config.emailRecipients.length) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(
        config.emailRecipients.join(','),
        customerId + ': Link Checker: Checking is ongoing',
        'Link checking is still running on account: ' + customerId +
            '. For more details see the spreadsheet: ' +
            CONFIG_SPREADSHEET_URL);
    setDateAsNow('dateEmailed');
```

I have noticed that the Script works fine for emails made out of a combination of numbers and letters but fails to send an email when the address contains other characters. Was wondering if anyone knows a workaround for this? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem sending emails to recipients with special characters *in the email address*. This example works fine:

```js
function main () {
  MailApp.sendEmail('postman42+some-other@gmail.com', 'test message', 'this works')
}
```

However, the script fill fail if one of the emails is not a valid email, like `mail1@example.com,-,mail2@example.com`. Consider filtering your config.emailRecipients for matching an email pattern before joining. A number of possible regular expressions for filtering could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)